# I got error when I run my app

Tags: swift, xcode7

While running app I get error:

> Thread:1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0×0)

My code:

```
 NotificationManager.updateNotif(params){
            (result:Bool) in
            if result {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                // バッジを-1に
                let val = NotificationManager.sharedInstance.notifTabbar.badgeValue

                if Int(val!)!/*val?.toInt()*/ > 0 {
                    let badgStr = Int(val!)!/*val!.toInt()!*/ - 1
                    if badgStr == 0 {
                        NotificationManager.sharedInstance.notifTabbar.badgeValue = nil
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                    }
                    else{
                        NotificationManager.sharedInstance.notifTabbar.badgeValue = String(stringInterpolationSegment: badgStr)
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgStr
```

Comment: yeah, we're going to need more information. What outcome are you expecting? Where does it crash?

Comment: I'm making yik yak clone then when I tapped a comment on notification in "Me", it happened.

Comment: above is the reason I got error for

Comment: the error also said that "fatal error : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Answer (score 0):

These sort of errors usually occur when you have unconnected links in your header files

i.e you had a button you added to header file, button was then deleted but declaration in header file is still there.

Check over your view controllers and header files to make sure this is not the case.